# On Boot: Random colors flashing in jagged formation then nothing

Tags: video, composite-video

I am using Raspbian 2013-07-26 and I have been having a *lot* of trouble with my Pi lately (cheap SD card I'm thinking, lots of corrupt stuff).

Anyways, when I try to boot it I get this on the screen (lines are more angular on screen, it's somewhat distorted because it's a picture of a screen:

[image: Screen during boot]

and then it goes to staticy nothing. 
I really hope I haven't nuked my Pi, but it looks that way, at least the RCA adapter. I can connect and do everything via the USB Console cable I have, but I don't get any graphics on my screen.

I did add some files via my MicroSD card reader (MicroSD slides into slot on the reader which goes to USB) right before the problems began. I have never used the reader before, so I don't know if this is unusual.

I haven't tried HDMI yet, but I will as soon as I can. I have re-imaged my SD card since this problem started using the same afore-mentioned SD card reader. I will try re-imaging with the MicroSD Card adapter (MicroSD to SD) in my SD card reader to see if that solves the problem.

Have I fried my RCA Video somehow, or is this because of something internal?

Please help, I really like my Raspberry Pi and don't want to have to pay for a new one.

**Edit:** I re-imaged using the MicroSD Card adapter (MicroSD to SD) and same problem.

Comment: Look at http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Power_.2F_Start-up

Comment: I did look at that, but it didn't help at all. None of those problems apply for me, because I have successfully used the *exact* same setup as I am using right now (during this problem.) I let it sit all night, but I have school, so I can't test out any new fixes right now. I will try HDMI and try the RCA again and post the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't why, but after letting it sit all night, it works again. Thanks for the help @Milliways, but it solved itself.

I'm thinking something might have tripped the F3 polyfuse as several of the components were *really* hot, including the fuse (as in burning my skin hot for the fuse).

Comment: Late comment/accept. Actually, my cable was loose.